# Scalding: Compare strings pairwise?

Tags: scala, hadoop, edit-distance, scalding

With Scalding I need to:

1. Group string fields by first 3 chars
2. Compare strings in all pairs in every group using `edit-distance` metric ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)
3. Write results in CSV file where record is `string; string; distance`

To group strings I use `map` and `groupBy` as in the following example:

```
import cascading.tuple.Fields
import com.twitter.scalding._

class Scan(args: Args) extends Job(args) {
  val output = TextLine("tmp/out.txt")

  val wordsList = List(
    ("aaaa"),
    ("aaabb"),
    ("aabbcc"),
    ("aaabccdd"),
    ("aaabbccdde"),
    ("aaabbddd"),
    ("bbbb"),
    ("bbbaaa"),
    ("bbaaabb"),
    ("bbbcccc"),
    ("bbbddde"),
    ("ccccc"),
    ("cccaaa"),
    ("ccccaabbb"),
    ("ccbbbddd"),
    ("cdddeee")
    )

  val orderedPipe =
    IterableSource[(String)](wordsList, ('word))
        .map('word -> 'key ){word:String => word.take(3)}
    .groupBy('key) {_.toList[String]('word -> 'x) }
        .debug
        .write(output)
}
```

As a result I get:

```
['aaa', 'List(aaabbddd, aaabbccdde, aaabccdd, aaabb, aaaa)']
['aab', 'List(aabbcc)']
['bba', 'List(bbaaabb)']
['bbb', 'List(bbbddde, bbbcccc, bbbaaa, bbbb)']
['ccb', 'List(ccbbbddd)']
['ccc', 'List(ccccaabbb, cccaaa, ccccc)']
['cdd', 'List(cdddeee)']
```

Now, in this example, I need to comute edit-distance for strings with `aaa` key in this list:

```
List(aaabbddd, aaabbccdde, aaabccdd, aaabb, aaaa)
```

next for all strings with 'bbb' key in this list:

```
List(bbbddde, bbbcccc, bbbaaa, bbbb)
```

etc.

To compute edit-distance between all strings in every group I need to replace `toList` with my own function, how can I do this? And also how can I write results of my function to a CSV file?

Thanks!

**Update**

How to get `List` from Scalding `Pipe`?

`toList` just returns another `Pipe` so I can't use it all:

```
  val orderedPipe =
    IterableSource[(String)](wordsList, ('word))
        .map('word -> 'key ){word:String => word.take(3)}
        .groupBy('key) {_.toList[String]('word -> 'x) }
        .combinations(2) //---ERROR! Pipe has no such method!
        .debug
        .write(output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edit-distance can be calculated as described in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance#Basic_algorithm):

```
def editDistance(a: String, b: String): Int = {

    import scala.math.min

    def min3(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) = min(min(x, y), z)

    val (m, n) = (a.length, b.length)

    val matrix = Array.fill(m + 1, n + 1)(0)

    for (i <- 0 to m; j <- 0 to n) {

        matrix(i)(j) = if (i == 0) j
                       else if (j == 0) i
                       else if (a(i-1) == b(j-1)) matrix(i-1)(j-1)
                       else min3(
                                 matrix(i - 1)(j) + 1,
                                 matrix(i)(j-1) + 1,
                                 matrix(i - 1)(j - 1) + 1) 
    }

    matrix(m)(n)
}
```

For finding pairwise edit-distance of elements of a list:

```
def editDistances(list: List[String]) = {

    list.combinations(2).toList.map(x => (x(0), x(1), editDistance(x(0), x(1))))
}
```

use this in groupBy:

```
  val orderedPipe =
      IterableSource[(String)](wordsList, ('word))
      .map('word -> 'key ){word:String => word.take(3)}
      .groupBy('key) {_.mapList[String, List[(String, String, Int)]]('word -> 'x)(editDistances)}
      .debug
      .write(output)
```

As far as writing to csv format is concerned, you can simply use the `com.twitter.scalding.Csv` class.

`write(Csv(outputFile))`

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I can not use `combinations` on Scalding `Pipe` type, bo such method. Please see my question update.

Comment: You should apply combinations on list of strings that you have already produced.

Comment: I can not produce a list of strings so far. Pipe function `toList` returns another Pipe not a List

Comment: Strange, but I get this error: `value mapValueStream is not a member of com.twitter.scalding.GroupBuilder` In what package `mapValueStream` is defined?

Comment: my mistake. please use mapList in groupBy. see update. (also note that editDistances now takes List and returns List)